# Trying to set the value of a Vuejs input computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form with fields bound to VueJs using v-model method. When a user selects an item from a drop-down, the fields are populated from a `$http` response.

HTML:

```
<form id="vApp">
  <input type="number" v-model="hourlyRate">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var thing = new Vue({
    el: '#vApp',
    data: {
       response: {}
    },
    computed: {
       hourlyRate: function(){
          return this.response.length > 0 ? 0 : this.response.hourlyRate;                       
       }
    },
    methods: {
       getHourlyRate: function(){
            this.$http.post('someUrl', {iWant: 'hourlyRate'},
                  function( response ){
                       this$set('response', response);
                   }
       }
    }
});
```

So the user gets a "canned" option for the input based on their dropdown, but I also want them to able to enter a value and that value to become the object's `hourlyRate` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a computed property like that. Just create the hourlyRate property and set it when you receive a response:

```
var thing = new Vue({
    el: '#vApp',
    data: {
       hourlyRate: 0
    },
    methods: {
       getHourlyRate: function(){
            this.$http.post('someUrl', {iWant: 'hourlyRate'},
                  function( response ){
                       this.hourlyRate = response.length > 0 ? 0 : response.hourlyRate;
                   }
       }
    }
});
```